# How to send the entire file over netty using camel

Tags: apache-camel, netty

I am trying to send over the contents of entire file using netty and camel;

```
    <camel:route>
                <camel:from uri="file://test/?fileName=sample.txt&amp;noop=true&amp;delete=false"/>
                <camel:convertBodyTo type="java.lang.String"/>
                <camel:to uri="netty:tcp://localhost:9012?textline=true&amp;sync=true"/>        
    </camel:route>
```

I have another route consuming at this end-point:

```
    <camel:route>
            <camel:from uri="netty:tcp://localhost:9012?textline=true&amp;sync=true"/>
            <camel:process ref="fileCollector"/>
    </camel:route>
```

the exchange at FileCollector::process() seem to contain the data line by line - for example -if the contents of the file is

> This is line one
>
> This is line two

the FileCollector::process() is called once per line, making it really difficult for me because my requirement is to process entire file and send the reply back.

Comment: improve your question, as people dont want/can help you if you do not show effort in your question

Comment: modified the question with some more details, hope it is clear now.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the textline=true codec which is a single line only codec - terminator char is a line break char.

To transfer the entire file, you need to build your own codec, or use any of the built-in such as the length codec.

You need to study more on Netty codecs how to do this.

Comment: I did pick up encoders and decoders but right now, I am struck at this error: "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find a suitable setter for property: decoder as there isn't a setter method with same type: java.lang.String nor type conversion possible: No type converter available to convert from type: java.lang.String to the required type: org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelHandler with value #eofDecoder"; looks like, Camel-Netty does not cast the bean name to the class type required; I use only spring dsl so I am finding it difficult.

Comment: You need to register your custom codec in the Camel registry, if you are not using spring xml with < bean > to do so.

Comment: looks like, that was error with incompatible Netty version (used the latest one); works with Netty 3.x; <bean id="eofDecoder" class="org.apache.camel.component.netty.ChannelHandlerFactories" factory-method="newLengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder">
            <constructor-arg value="1048576"/>
            <constructor-arg value="0"/>
            <constructor-arg value="4"/>
            <constructor-arg value="0"/>
            <constructor-arg value="4"/>
 </bean> but right now looking at an another error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unsupported message type: class java.lang.String